# node wordpress upload media success but not good

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, xml-rpc

I try to upload an image to a wordpress site with node,
I get a successful response but when I view the image I see no image.

the node code:

```js
let wordpress = require("./wordpress");
let base64 = require('node-base64-image');
let imageType = require('image-type');

module.exports = function(url) {

 let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  base64.encode(url, {}, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
    return reject(err);
   }
   let base64Image = data.toString('base64');
   let imageMime = imageType(data);
          
   mediaData = {
    type: imageMime.mime,
    name: 'tzook.jpg',
    overwrite: true,
    bits: base64Image
   }

   wordpress.uploadFile(mediaData, function(error, id) {
    if (error) {
     return reject(error);
    }
    return resolve(id)
   })
  });
   
 });
 return promise;
}
```

in the bottom line I pass the base64 encoded string, that I know it works as I checked the string itself.

the successful response:

```js
{ attachment_id: '561',
  date_created_gmt: 2016-07-04T03:29:01.000Z,
  parent: 0,
  link: 'http://www.mmayou.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tzook-4.jpg',
  title: 'tzook.jpg',
  caption: '',
  description: '',
  metadata: '',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  thumbnail: 'http://www.mmayou.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tzook-4.jpg',
  id: '561',
  file: 'tzook.jpg',
  url: 'http://www.mmayou.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tzook-4.jpg' }
```

The response is

Answer (score 1):

It is simply passing the buffer itself instead of the base64 string...

the code:

```
//not this....
//let base64Image = data.toString('base64');
let imageMime = imageType(data);

mediaData = {
    type: imageMime.mime,
    name: 'tzook.jpg',
    overwrite: true,
    bits: data     // but simply the buffer itself
}
```

the answer is from: github repo
https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress/issues/44